# Initiate a 'save as' dialog for files which reside on a remote server

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, save-as

I'm writing a web page (using spring mvc) which displays a list of files that the user can download. I would like the 'save as' dialog to open when user choose a file and clicks the download button. To my best understanding, i can use href with the path to the file (or use window.location), however the files that should be downloaded are located in a different server and need to be fetched from there first.

There are two options that i have thought of, both have big flaws:
1. use window.location with a link to a spring mvc controller. in the controller make a call to fetch the file and set its content on the response (with content-disposition header).
The problem is that for large files, it will take some time for the save as dialog to open (As the file needs to be fetched from the remote server first) and i have no way of 'telling' the user that the download has started.
2. make an http call that will retrieve the file from the second server (and have some kind of indication while the http promise has not yet resolved), save it on my server, return the path to the file in the response and than call window.location with the returned path.
In this case, the downloaded files will need to somehow get deleted at the end of the download.

Any ideas and thoughts?

Thanks a lot!